# Redirect to subdomain on http request or request without protocol on https website

Tags: laravel, nginx, redirect, https, digital-ocean

I have a subdomain at
https://numan-rest.allrestaurants.us/
however if I try to open it with **http** like
http://numan-rest.allrestaurants.us/
or with **www** `www.numan-rest.allrestaurants.us`
I am getting redirected to the main domain at `allrestaurants.us/`
I want to stay in subdomain even if I request with **HTTP**, without any protocol and with **WWW**

this is how my nginx conf looks like in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        root /var/www/allrest/public;
        

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        charset utf-8;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    # Enable nginx status page for Zabbix
    location = /basic_status {
                stub_status;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }
    
    # Enable php-fpm status page for Zabbix
        location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
                ## disable access logging for request if you prefer
                access_log off;

                ## Only allow trusted IPs for security, deny everyone else
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                ## Now the port or socket of the php-fpm pool we want the status of
                # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
                fastcgi_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico)$ {
               expires 30d;
               add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
        }


        error_log /var/log/nginx/allrest_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/allrest_access.log;

     

}
```

and this is laravel routes

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.' . config('allrest.app_domain')], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'SubdomainController@show');
 });

Route::group(['domain' => 'www.{subdomain}.' . config('allrest.app_domain')], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'SubdomainController@show');
});
```

I tried with adding
`return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`
at the end of nginx conf but that prevent accessing the website completetly
and chrome give error `To many redirects`
and this is how my digital ocean DNS rules are
[digitalocean Dns Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzyUS.png)
No load balancer at digital ocean
[Load Balancer Digital ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Bb8.png)
However I found some rules in firewall setting I don't know if it has something to do with these rules
Here is the picture [Firewall rules Digital ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbpQv.png)

Comment: You don't actually have an https listener or any http to https rule in your configuration at all so the redirection from http to https must be happening somewhere else like e.g. at a load balancer or proxy that you're not disclosing here.

Comment: No proxy and load balancer in Digital ocean

Comment: You will probably need to check the configuration in the load balancer to see what is happening. As I mentioned you do not have any HTTPS handler in this configuration meaning that HTTPS is handled at the load balancer end

Comment: as I mentioned earlier no load balancer setup at digital ocean, I have updated the questions and added the images of load balancer and firewall settings

Comment: The question remains then, you are listening on port 80 on your nginx configuration you shared. Where is HTTPS (port 443) handled and where is the HTTP to HTTPS redirect handled? Check more of your nginx settings in case you missed something there

Comment: Is there any other file where I should look for the configuration, Kindly provide me the file path that will be helpful